# how to put the results in a table or array in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hi
I have a list of numbers for example k_1,k_2,...k_n, and f is a function.
Now I apply f on the list of numbers and I need those numbers such that f is increasing,i.e.

```
f(k_i)>f(k_j) for any i>j .
```

I can get the results number k_i's each in different line, but I need the results in one table separated with comma or something else and counting the number of results.

For example:

```
k = Table[k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9, k10];
count = 0;
i=1;
For[j = i, j <= 10, j++, 
  If[f[k[[j]]] - f[k[[i]]] > 0, i = j; Print["k", i];
   count = count + 1]];
Print["count= ", count]
```

I got the result like:

```
k2
k3
k5
k9
count=4
```

but I need the results to be together:

```
{k2,k3,k5,k9} 
count=4
```

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Print`, you could do `AppendTo`, ie

`list={};AppendTo[list,5]`

It might be good to start learning functional programming approach as Mathematica has tools to make it efficient, your above code might look something like this

```
pairs = Partition[list, 2, 1];
increasingPairs = Select[pairs, f[First[#]] < f[Last[#]] &];
Last /@ increasingPairs
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want the longest increasing subsequence. The simplest and most efficient way I am aware of to get it in Mathematica is the following:

```
lis[f_, vals_List] := LongestCommonSequence[#, Sort[#]] &[Map[f, vals]];
```

Example:

```
In[8]:= lis[# &, {5, 3, 6, 1, 5, 7}]

Out[8]= {5, 6, 7}
```

In principle, the answer is not unique - there may be several different longest increasing subsequences with the same length.